# What is 'intel(R) ICH10 family USB enhanced host controller - 3A3A'?

Tags: windows-10, usb, motherboard, android, usb-3

I have a Samsung Galaxy S8.  I have never had problems syncing with my PC in the past however this weekend I have started having problems as described here: https://superuser.com/users/254353/w0051977 i.e. I see this error when attempting to sync:

[image]

I spent 12 hours trying lots of different things suggested online.  I decided to disable: `intel(R) ICH10 family USB enhanced host controller - 3A3A` (a USB controller in device manager) and then my Galaxy S8 was recognised.  However, once I enable it again then I see the warning and my device does not connect (or loses its connection).

What can I do about this? I have tried reinstalling Windows 10 already.  This is my motherboard: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/P6X58DE/HelpDesk_Download/.  Do I need to reinstall the chipset drivers? If the answer is yes, then were do I find the chipset drivers?

Update

Following on from grawitys' comment.  Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

Here is my motherboard advert for the USB ports:

[image]

Here is the cable: [link](https://www.argos.co.uk/product/8018960?&cmpid=GS001&_$ja=tsid:59158%7Cacid:532-198-3455%7Ccid:598893978%7Cagid:24310580450%7Ctid:aud-641224040817:pla-447996846435%7Ccrid:86865568610%7Cnw:g%7Crnd:3324847289051218358%7Cdvc:c%7Cadp:1o1%7Cmt:%7Cloc:&gclid=EAIaIQobChMItua2seWY5QIVSrDtCh01LgDHEAQYASABEgLeyfD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds).

I have tried plugging in the device to all USB slots.

I have no issue with any other device.

Comment: 1) Are you connecting the phone to a Type-C port, or to a USB 3.0 port, or to a 2.0 port? Are you using a USB 3.x cable or a 2.0 cable? 2) Switch Device Manager to "View by connection". When you connect the phone successfully, which USB controller does it show up under? 3) Can you successfully connect other USB 2.0 devices to the same port, with the controller enabled?

Comment: @grawity, I have edited my post with an update, which answers your questions.

Comment: As that is a "charging" cable it might be that it has resistors in the cable to indicate to the computer that it should always provide power. It might interfere with your computer actually detecting what the device is. Have you tried with the cable that came with the phone?

Comment: @Mokubai, yes I have and I get the same problem.  I bought the cable in the link today in case there was an issue with the cable that came with the phone.  Both cables work perfectly on my tablet and mac.  It is just the PC with issues.  Plus I have had the android for years and only started experiencing problems this weekend.

Comment: Okay, so not that then... this page has a Microsoft Troubleshooter that might fix some USB based problems. It was for Windows 7 but according to the page also works on 8 and 10. https://www.windowscentral.com/how-fix-common-usb-problems-windows-10

Comment: @Mokubai, no problems were identified when I ran it.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @w0051977 Only generic stuff like https://support.hp.com/gb-en/document/c03327635 Step 7 suggests right-clicking and uninstalling the device that shows up wrongly to force the driver to reinstall when you unplug and replug it. It sounds like an update may have corrupted the driver somehow.

Comment: @Mokubai, is it possible to reinstall the driver? Also, wouldn't the fact that I reinstalled windows today fix that?

Comment: Hmm, if the motherboard is supposed to have USB 3.0 ports, why is there no XHCI controller in Device Manager...